# How to add a Checkbox in the repeater and the checkbox should be mutually exclusive check box

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox

I am using a Repeater control with some attributes like name, age, address and filling these details from the database. I want to use a check box on the Repeater. so when a user click on a checkbox, I want to show the selected details on other panel. My issues is How to add a Checkbox in the repeater and the checkbox should be mutually exclusive check box

Comment: the easiest solution would be to use a radio instead of a checkbox?

Comment: @cecilozaur How can we do when user want to uncheck the selected option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well then do, assuming you have jquery

```
$('checkboxSelector').on('click', function () {
    var me = $(this);
    if(me.is(':checked')) //uncheck all other options
    {
        $(':checkbox').not(me).filter(':checked').prop('checked', false);
    }
})
```